# Interact MS Access with C#

Tags: c#, ms-access

Ineed to add some XML features to one MSAccess project. Easyest way for me to done this job is to write some C# code whic is going to read data and write that to local disk in XML. What I do not know is how to interact acces with c# trought user interface of ms access. What I looking for is some kind of CLR as exist in MSSQL databases wher you can call c# library from stored proc or udfs. Or i shold simple write console app and call it from MS access with params.

Comment: I don't think you can call directly C# from VBA... but yes, you could call an external EXE written in C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read and write XML with VBA also.

http://msaccess-dox.net/MS.Press-Programming.Microsoft1/8368final/LiB0113.html

Otherwise, you can create a COM class that would expose these functionality and call that from your Access application

Answer (score 1):

You can read/write to access databases using the [Jet Engine from C#](http://www.google.nl/search?hl=nl&client=opera&hs=Kc3&rls=en&channel=suggest&q=Jet+Engine+%2Bc%23&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=)

However, automating Forms, Reports and Macro (VBA Modules) is going to be hard if at all possible

Comment: this works, but the more comfortable LINQ2SQL is not supported yet